# C size_t and ssize_t negative value

Tags: c, size-t

`size_t` is declared as `unsigned int` so it can't represent negative value.
So there is `ssize_t` which is the *signed* type of `size_t` right?
Here's my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){
size_t a = -25;
ssize_t b = -30;
printf("%zu\n%zu\n", a, b);
return 0;
}
```

why i got:

```
18446744073709551591
18446744073709551586
```

as result?
I know that with `size_t` this could be possible because it is an unsigned type but why i got a wrong result also with `ssize_t`??

Comment: You're using the wrong format specifier.

Comment: `ssize_t` isn't in standard C, it comes from POSIX. The closes in standard C that comes to `ssize_t` is `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned integral type, but it's usuall not `unsigned int`.  Typically is equivalent to `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the first case you're assigning to an unsigned type - `a`. In the second case you're using the wrong format specifier. The second specifier should be `%zd` instead of `%zu`.

Comment: @cnicutar  Not familiar with POSIX details.  Since `printf("%zu", b)` expects a integer of `sizeof(size_t)`, is sizeof(size_t) always the same as sizeof(ssize_t) as not to cause mischief?  Or is `printf("%zu", (size_t) b)` needed?

Comment: Is `ssize_t` defined to be the same size as `size_t`?  If not, `"%zd"` is not a portable answer.  Suggest `printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) b);`

Comment: @chux `%zd` is the specifier prescribed for `ssize_t`. *A following integer conversion corresponds to a `size_t` or `ssize_t` argument.*

Comment: @cnicutar  Thanks.  As `ssize_t` is not specified in C, where might I find that `"%zd"` specifier prescription for future reference?

Comment: @chux I quoted a linux man page on printf. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) also mentions it, though not as clearly.

Comment: @cnicutar Again thanks: Goggled "linux man page on printf" and found it.  Note: The provided link (Open Group Base Specification) had nothing on `ssize_t`.

Comment: @chux Ah, but it mentions *a signed integer type corresponding to a size_t argument*.

Comment: @cnicutar A little late here, but I don't read *a signed integer type corresponding to a size_t argument* as explicitly referring to `ssize_t`. The definition of `ssize_t` never links it to `size_t` in any way.  The [entire definition is merely](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):  "Used for a count of bytes or an error indication." and "The type `ssize_t` shall be capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, {SSIZE_MAX}]."  And [the defintion of `SSIZE_MAX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) is circular.

Comment: (cont) A `ssize_t` larger than `size_t` would also address the issue that you can legally try to `read()` more bytes than `read()` can indicate success for when `size_t` and `ssize_t` both have the same size. So it's not unreasonable to allow for a `ssize_t` larger than `size_t`, thus the lack of linkage in the standard between `size_t` and `ssize_t` may very well be deliberate. I'll admit I've never seen such a system and printing `ssize_t` with `%zd` "works" on every system I've used, but IMO it's not pedantically correct. And this is definitely well down the "language lawyer" rabbit hole...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should check the actual size of the two types.
Something like the following snippet should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  printf( "sizeof(  size_t ) = %d bytes\n",(int) sizeof( size_t) );
  printf( "sizeof( ssize_t ) = %d bytes\n",(int) sizeof( ssize_t) );
  return 0;
}
```

I get (64bit Linux, GCC v7.2) "8 bytes" in both cases, which is the same as long int and long long int, the maximum CPU-native integer value.

When the sizes are the same (and they should always be), `size_t` can have "2x larger absolute values" than `ssize_t` which, in turn, can have signed (that's either positive or negative) values.

If they were different, then the larger one would be ... larger and could thus accommodate for larger values.

But in the end, `ssize_t` and `size_t` are two different types used to "talk" about sizes, lengths, amounts of memory and so on.

The former is just ditching 1 bit for the value in order to gain the sign needed to signal some sort of error.

Finally, the two types are not interchangeable, not always at least.
When the size can go past 2^63 bytes/items the difference is clear.
`size_t` won't overflow while `ssize_t` will.

Under "normal" circumstances you can cast from one to the other one.
For the cases I mentioned earlier, you should never mix them.

Just as a reference, both `strlen()` and `malloc()` use `size_t`, while both `read()` and `readv()` use ssize_t.

So, `ssize_t` **is not** the signed version of `size_t` as there are values in `ssize_t` that cannot be mapped on a `size_t` (like `-1`) and viceversa. And library functions either use one type or the other one.

Then, to your questions, the two numbers you see differ by 5 units, that's exactly what you'd expect. What you see is the value of those two variables when seen as `unsigned long`. Try printing them as `signed long` (`%ld`) instead so you can still see the sign.

Comment: Note: [Linux Programmer's Manual PRINTF(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) does have "z: A following integer conversion corresponds to a _size_t_ or _ssize_t_ argument".

Comment: Despite the (bad) wording, `z` is a length modifier, not a  conversion specifier. IMHO, I would use `%ld` or `%lu` based upon their specific usage and meaning. But this is also subject to personal tastes.

Comment: "they have non-overlapping realms." - false, they overlap and the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3... are in the overlapping part

Comment: Ah ah ah! `:-D` Sure. I meant that functions either use `size_t` or `ssize_t`, never both tmk.

Answer (score 0):

> ... why i got a wrong result also with `ssize_t`??

Use

```
ssize_t b = -30;
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) b);
```

Use a matching specifier, which for a negative `ssize_t` is **not** `%zu` nor certainly `"%zd"`.
[How to use “zd” specifier with `printf()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359).

```
ssize_t b = -30;
printf("%zu\n", b);  // problem.
```

---

`ssize_t` does not have a C specified print specifier.  C does not even specify `ssize_t`.

Various extensions to C do specify `ssize_t` and in a case of Linux, the print specifier also. 
[Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) does have:

> z: A following integer conversion corresponds to a `size_t` or `ssize_t` argument",

```
printf("%zd\n", b);  // OK for that Linux
```

[POSIX B.2.12 Data Types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_12) has

> `ssize_t` This is intended to be a signed analog of `size_t`. The wording is such that an implementation may either choose to use a longer type or simply to use the signed version of the type that underlies `size_t`.

---

Since `ssize_t` may (uncommonly) be wider than `size_t`, using `"%zd"` could invoke *undefined behavior* (UB).   It is simple enough to cast to the widest standard signed type since C99 as `intmax_t` and print.

```
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) b);  // OK for general use
```

Answer (score -4):

Overflow coz size_t is a UNSIGNED
when you try to set size_t as (-val)
you get overflow and get SIZE_T_MAX - val

for example:
size_t val = -20;
//val == 18446744073709551615 - 20;