# Is 'signed size_t' different from 'ssize_t'?

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I compile with ndk-build, it shows an error message:

> warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but
>   argument 5 has type 'ssize_t'.

I thought `ssize_t` was the same as `signed size_t`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Android, `size_t` is `unsigned int`, but `ssize_t` is `long int`. To print or log `ssize_t`, simply use **`"%ld"`**.

See [sys/types.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/a34817457feee026e8702a1d2dffe9e92b51d7d1/libc/include/sys/types.h#123):

> Traditionally, bionic's `ssize_t` was `long int`. This caused GCC to emit warnings when you pass a `ssize_t` to a `printf()`-style function. The correct type is `__kernel_ssize_t`, which is `int`, which isn't an ABI change for C code (because they're the same size)  but is an ABI change for C++ because `int` and `long int` mangle to `i` and `l` respectively. So until we can fix the ABI, this change should not be propagated to the NDK.

Note that on other platforms, using `%zd` is [preferable](/a/12175397/192373).

Comment: Ooof.  No.  Both *`ssize_t` is `long int`* and *To print or log `ssize_t`, simply use **"%ld"*** are wrong.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175358/c-size-t-and-ssize-t-negative-value

Comment: @AndrewHenle you are right in principle. But the question was specifically marked as Android. Please see my update.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `ssize_t` varies from system to system. Sometimes it's `int`, sometimes it's `long`.  There are probably also systems on which it's defined as `long long int`.

`ssize_t` is *supposed* to be a signed integer that is the same width as `size_t`, so `%zd` works for `ssize_t` in *sane* build system configurations.

Unfortunately, the error message you're seeing indicates that your build system configuration is broken. It looks like this is a known issue for Android. If you're seeing it elsewhere, it's very likely that you are cross-compiling for another platform but getting some of your system include files from the wrong place. Check that your build is using the right compiler and that the compiler's sysroot set correctly.

If you just work around the problem by changing your printf(), you'll likely just run into worse, weirder problems later.

Comment: `printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)ssize);` is probably better, especially for 64-bit Windows platforms where `long` is just an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewHenle for pointing that out.  I thought about revising to use PRIdMAX and intmax_t, but the main point of my answer is really to say that the build system configuration is broken, so I decided to just focus on that. Besides, if the build system config is broken, PRIdMAX and intmax_t are probably wrong too.