# How to use "zd" specifier with `printf()`?

Tags: c, printf

Looking for clarification on using `"zd"` with `printf()`.

Certainly the following is correct with C99 and later.

```
void print_size(size_t sz) {
  printf("%zu\n", sz);
}
```

The C spec *seems* to allow `printf("%zd\n", sz)` depending on how it is read:

7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function

> `z` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument; or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed integer type corresponding to `size_t` argument.  C11dr §7.21.6.1 7

Should this be read as

1. "`z` Specifies that a following `d` ... conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument ... "(both types) and "`z` Specifies that a following `u` ... conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument ..." (both types)

OR

2. "`z` Specifies that a following `d` ... conversion specifier applies to a corresponding signed integer type argument ..." (signed type only) and "`z` Specifies that a following `u` ... conversion specifier applies to a `size_t`" (unsigned type only).

I've been using the #2 definition, but now not so sure.

> Which is correct, 1, 2, or something else?
>
> If #2 is correct, what is an example of a type that can use `"%zd"`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`printf` with a `"%zd"` format expects an argument of the signed type that corresponds to the unsigned type `size_t`.

Standard C doesn't provide a name for this type or a good way to determine what it is.  If `size_t` is a typedef for `unsigned long`, for example, then `"%zd"` expects an argument of type `long`, but that's not a portable assumption.

The standard requires that corresponding signed and unsigned types use the same representation for the non-negative values that are representable in both types. A footnote says that this is meant to imply that they're interchangeable as function arguments. So this:

```
size_t s = 42;
printf("s = %zd\n", s);
```

should work, and should print "42". It will interpret the value `42`, of the unsigned type `size_t`, as if it were of the corresponding signed type. But there's really no good reason to do that, since `"%zu"` is also correct and well defined, without resorting to additional language rules. And `"%zu"` works for *all* values of type `size_t`, including those outside the range of the corresponding signed type.

Finally, POSIX defines a type `ssize_t` in the headers [`<unistd.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) and [`<sys/types.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html). Though POSIX doesn't explicitly say so, it's likely that `ssize_t` will be the signed type corresponding to `size_t`.
So if you're writing POSIX-specific code, `"%zd"` is (probably) the correct format for printing values of type `ssize_t`.

UPDATE: POSIX [explicitly says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html) that `ssize_t` *isn't* necessarily the signed version of `size_t`, so it's unwise to write code that assumes that it is:

> **`ssize_t`**
>
> This is intended to be a signed analog of `size_t`. The wording is such
> that an implementation may either choose to use a longer type or
> simply to use the signed version of the type that underlies `size_t`.
> All functions that return `ssize_t` (`read()` and `write())` describe as
> "implementation-defined" the result of an input exceeding {`SSIZE_MAX`}.
> It is recognized that some implementations might have `int`s that are
> smaller than `size_t`. A conforming application would be constrained not
> to perform I/O in pieces larger than {`SSIZE_MAX`}, but a conforming
> application using extensions would be able to use the full range if
> the implementation provided an extended range, while still having a
> single type-compatible interface. The symbols `size_t` and `ssize_t` are
> also required in `<unistd.h>` to minimize the changes needed for calls
> to `read()` and `write()`. Implementors are reminded that it must be
> possible to include both `<sys/types.h>` and `<unistd.h>` in the same
> program (in either order) without error.

Comment: @MK.: That's weird. It says you edited my answer 2 hours ago (I don't object to that) and deleted 2 characters in the body, but I don't see a change.

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah I had to.  It wouldn't allow me to replace downvote with up vote because it' sbeen 2 hours.  Which is completely moronic because I can edit and change.  I asked on meta to remove the limitation of people who have enough rep to edit, but it didn't go anywhere.  The change was removing extra blank line before the link footnotes which are not displayed, so you can't see it (I honestly tried coming up with a meaningful edit but the answer was too good :)

Comment: OK, no problem. It just seemed odd that I couldn't see any change in the edit history.

Comment: "The standard requires that corresponding signed and unsigned types use the same representation for the non-negative values that are representable in both types." --> Is that due to C11 §6.5.2.2 6?

Comment: @chux: 6.2.6.2p5: "A valid (non-trap) object representation
of a signed integer type where the sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the corresponding unsigned type, and shall represent the same value." I just noticed that doesn't specify the other direction, though it would require a peculiar representation with multiple representations for the same non-zero value to break the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

According to the little test I have done, "zd" is always true ,but "zu" don't work for negative numbers.

Test Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main (void)
  {  int i;
     size_t uzs = 1;
     ssize_t zs = -1;
    for ( i= 0; i<5 ;i++, uzs <<= 16,zs <<= 16 )
    {
       printf ("%zu\t", uzs); /*true*/
       printf ("%zd\t", uzs); /*true*/

       printf ("%zu\t", zs); /* false*/
       printf ("%zd\n", zs); /*true*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's this about "true" and "false"?

Comment: Thanks for the test, but certain  '"zd" is always true' will fail when `uzs` is large like `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: Testing is **not** the correct way to determine if things are legal in C.

Comment: Note that when given a negative value, %u will always report something else (in a well-defined way)

Comment: @Phlarx "%u will always report something else (in a well-defined way)" --> it it _not_ well defined, yet commonly that _undefined behavior_ is not objectionable.

Comment: @chux I meant well-defined as in: the bit pattern for any specific unsigned number is well-defined. Either way, the transition from signed to unsigned will likely be predictable and consistent per architecture. I wouldn't go so far as to say undefined, though, since the C standard only calls out 2's comp, 1's comp, and sign-mag as possibilities. More like implementation-defined, or architecture-defined. But this is semantics at this point.