# Is the %zd specifier an optional feature in C11?

Tags: c, scanf, c11, format-specifiers

I have used a very simple code:

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t variable;
    /*prompt*/
    printf("enter the value of the variable: ");
    scanf("%zd", variable);
    printf("you entered %zd value of the variable", variable);
}
```

Howeve, the GCC compiler produces the following result:

```
Enter the vale of the size_t variable: 15
You entered zd value of size_t type
Process returned 35 (0X23)  execution time: 3.094s
Press any key to continue
```

My book also demonstrates the above example directly without mentioning that it is some kind of a special format specifier if library files were to be included.
Even [the online compiler](http://ideone.com) is not producing correct results.
Why is the code not working?

Comment: Because you called `printf` without passing the argument for the specifier.

Comment: If you turned on more warnings, you'd see that you passed the *value* of `variable` instead of its *address* to `scanf()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "zd" specifier with \`printf()\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916575/how-to-use-zd-specifier-with-printf)

Comment: `"%zd"` is expects a matching `signed size_t` argument, but in your case `size_t variable;` is `long unsigned int`. What are you trying there?

Comment: Chapter 1 of any beginner-level programming book should explain how to use these functions. You must also figure out how to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @Lundin, it was a typing error, I'm sorry

Answer (score 6):

```
scanf("%zd", variable);
```

Is undefined behavior because you didn't pass a pointer.

```
printf("you entered %zd value of the variable");
```

Is also undefined behavior because you used a format specifier but didn't pass a matching argument.

`%zd` is a mandatory feature of a hosted implementation of C11. Meaning it is mandatory for any compiler that implements stdio.h. However, `%zd` doesn't make much sense since `size_t` is always unsigned. Use `%zu` instead.

Please note that non-compliant implementations of the standard library exists, most notably Microsoft's implementation for Windows. The Microsoft implementation of the standard library is used by Visual Studio and also by the gcc/mingw compiler. This library does not support `%zu` properly since it does not follow the C11 standard.

Comment: And the answer to the question? _Is the %zd specifier an optional feature in C11?_

Comment: @KeineLust, sorry it was a typo

Comment: @KeineLust Updated.

Comment: @Lundin, please take a look at this: http://pasteboard.co/BkGB7RbyX.png

Comment: @bzal See my note about using non-standard compilers above. I'm guessing you are using gcc/Mingw under Windows (default compiler for Codeblocks in Windows), in which case you get exactly that result. The reason is that Mingw uses Microsoft's crappy non-standard library.

Comment: @Lundin , which compiler(/IDE) should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Nopes, `%zd` is one of the required format specifiers for an implementation to be conforming, it's not *optional*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()`

> `z` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies
>   to an argument with **type pointer to `size_t` or the corresponding signed
>   integer type.**

That said, in your code, the usage is wrong, for two reasons.

1. You need to pass a pointer-to-type as the argument for the supplied conversion specifier.
2. `size_t` is defined to be of unsigned integer type, so you should use the appropriate format specifier, `%zu`, not `%zd`.

   Quoting `C11` again, chapter §7.19

   > `size_t`
   >
   > which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

Something like

```
 scanf("%zu", &variable);
```

should work fine.

Comment: Your point 2. As OP is talking about `gcc` ... good to say that `%zd` displays it as though it were signed.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, it still prints zd

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, http://pasteboard.co/BkhCHgjhM.png

Comment: @bzal not `%zd`, use `%zu`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , http://pasteboard.co/BkGB7RbyX.png , I used %zu as well

Comment: @bzal Then your compiler is broken, what is it you're using?

Comment: @SouravGhosh , I'm using codeblocks with the MinGW(GCC compiler)

Comment: @bzal well, [for me, ideone shows expected result](https://ideone.com/t547B8).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136322/discussion-between-bzal-and-sourav-ghosh).