# Please explain this declaration of the POSIX getline() function

Tags: c

I see this line right after include and before main function.

```
size_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

What I can deduce

- getline is a function that takes three input parameters. I also understand the FILE pointer (3rd argument)

Where I'm stuck

- I do not understand the other two input parameters and size_t getline.
- Is size_t the type here?
- Also what is the meaning of two `*`s? I thought a single `*` is for pointer.

Comment: See the function description at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: You might care to note that POSIX says that [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) returns a `ssize_t` (a signed type the same size as the unsigned type `size_t`).   So, if the `<stdio.h>` header is included and the POSIX declarations are enabled, the code won't compile because of the difference between the official prototype and the one quoted in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "`ssize_t` (a signed type the **same size** as the unsigned type `size_t`)" --> I've looked for POSIX that specifies this,  [e.g.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), yet failed.  Know of any citation?  AFAIK, `ssize_t` could be wider.

Comment: @chux: You're right.  I'd expect to find the information in the POSIX [data types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) section, where it doesn't say what I want it to say (it just says: _`ssize_t` — Signed integer type used for a count of bytes or an error indication_).  So it appears that POSIX doesn't specify that it must be the same size as `size_t`. Let me know when you find an implementation that uses different sizes for `ssize_t` and `size_t`. (This doesn't affect my key point — `getline()` is declared to return `ssize_t` and not `size_t`).

Comment: The failure of POSIX for me `ssize_t`, my professor of physic will cry for this non sense. It's like the `isize` of rust. Trust me I'm `-1m` tail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I became interested in this when posting [%zd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_t` is a type.  It is probably defined in one of the header files that are included.  The function returns a value of that type, and its second parameter is a pointer to a value of that type.

You are correct that `*` indicates a pointer.  So `**` is a pointer to a pointer.  So the function parameter `lineptr` is the address of a location (A) in memory, which contains the address of another location (B) in memory; the data at the second location should be interpreted as `char` values.  This implies that the function could change the value stored at location A to point to some location other than B.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer variable needs memory to store value that is a address of memory. If you want to define a pointer variable to store address of a int type variable, you can define the pointer like this:

```
int *mypointer = NULL;
int x = 10;
//store the address of variable x
mypointer = &x;
```

As we know, the pointer variable is just to store someone's address that is just a number. Thus that pointer variable also has address in the memory space. How to store the pointer's address? We can do that like this:

```
int *mypointer = NULL;
int x = 10;
//the pointer store the x's address
mypointer = &x;

//define a pointer to store the pointer variable mypointer's address
int **newpointer = &mypointer;
```

So, char ** is similar with int **.

The type size_t is unsigned int or other type. Note size_t is unsigned type whatever size_t is type of int or someone else. Type ssize_t is signed type in C. For simplicity, size_t **maybe** define as follow:

```
typedef  unsigned int size_t;
typedef int ssize_t;
```

Comment: It may also be defined equivalent to `typedef unsigned long size_t;` or `typedef unsigned long long size_t;` or however else the implementation sees fit.

Comment: Yes，you are right.  In fact, we should not guess the precise definition of size_t. But we can get the its definition in someone C head file. This is cool  if we can make sense in difference between size_t  and ssize_t . For instance,  the type size_t and ssize_t  in  the function of read 
 or write  determine how maximum bytes these functions can operate(read from file or write into file). The reture type of these function is ssize_t so that these functions return -1 when they failed to call. But that limits the functions ability  to operate  bytes from or to file.