# strlen not returning correct number of characters

Tags: c, string, strlen

For some reason when I input `/bin/echo` followed by enter, strlen here says 14 when it should be 10. I can't seem to figure out why.

```
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];   // BUF_SIZE = 100
ssize_t readIn = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, BUF_SIZE);

printf("strlen=%lu\n", strlen(buffer));
```

Is it something to do with `/` character??

EDIT:

This is what buffer prints out when I loop through one char at a time:

```
#0: c=/ / hex=2f
#1: c=b / hex=62
#2: c=i / hex=69
#3: c=n / hex=6e
#4: c=/ / hex=2f
#5: c=e / hex=65
#6: c=c / hex=63
#7: c=h / hex=68
#8: c=o / hex=6f
#9: c=
 / hex=a
#10: c= / hex=5
#11: c=? / hex=ffffff90
#12: c=? / hex=ffffffff
#13: c= / hex=7f
```

Comment: The above code prints out `strlen=10` when I run it.

Comment: Try adding: `for (int i=0; i<strlen(buffer); i++) printf("#%i:  c=%c / hex=%x\n", i, buffer[i], buffer[i]);` after your code, then you see what characters are showing up in your string (both as ASCII chars and as their hexadecimal values; consult an ASCII chart for the meaning of any chars you don't recognize)

Comment: Where do you 0-terminate your array to make it a valid string? Your posted code invokes undefined behavior...

Comment: I added the code @JeremyFriesner. I wasn't away of that about read not null terminating. That makes sense then, thanks

Comment: What is the value of `readIn`?

Comment: regarding: `ssize_t readIn = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, BUF_SIZE);`  the `buffer` is an array and in C referencing an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So your (effectively) passing an address of an address.  Not what you want.  Strongly suggest removing the '&' from the parameter 'buffer'

Comment: OT:  always check the value returned from `read()`  if it is 0 then the other end of the connection closed.  if it is < 0 then some error occurred and the code should call: `perror( "read failed" );`  That will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: how should i handle if `read()` is 0? @user3629249

Comment: *how should i handle if read() is 0?*  that means the other end of the link has closed (I.E. EOF encountered)

Answer (score 7):

`strlen()` is for determining the length of a *string*. In C, A *string* has a *null character* at the end,else it is not a string.  Unless the data read includes a null character, it is not a string.

Instead, use the return value from `read()` to determine the length read.  To print a `ssize_t`, cast to a wide type, such as `long long` or `intmax_t` (better), as `ssize_t`  lacks a specified print specifier.<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>

Note: drop the `&` from buffer as it is not needed.

```
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];   // BUF_SIZE = 100
// ssize_t readIn = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, BUF_SIZE);
ssize_t readIn = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUF_SIZE);

// printf("strlen=%lu\n", strlen(buffer));
printf("length = %lld\n", (long long) readIn);
// or
printf("length = %jd\n", (intmax_t) readIn);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) does have "z: A following integer conversion corresponds to a `size_t` or
              `ssize_t` argument", so there code can use `printf("length = %zd\n", readIn);`

<sup>2</sup> POSIX allows either a wider type or the [*signed analog of* `size_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal).

Comment: `%zd` is the format for the signed type corresponding to (unsigned) `size_t`. Or if the value is non-negative, `%zu` is valid too.

Comment: @R.. True that [`"%zd"` can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359) for the signed type corresponding to (unsigned) `size_t`, yet `ssize_t` is not specified to be that type by C - or even exist.  In the case of `*nix`, I am not aware of such a _specified_ correspondence either, - so [_presumably_ `ssize_t` will be the signed type corresponding to `size_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926467/2410359).

Comment: `ssize_t` is part of POSIX.

Comment: @R.. Any POSIX cite that establishes  1) `"%zd"` for `ssize_t` or 2) range/size correspondence of `ssize_t` and "signed type corresponding to (unsigned) `size_t`" to take this from a reasonable assumption to a spec?  Note that OP's post  is not tagged as to which extension of C being use, yet `read()` is commonly associate with `*nix` like code and so a reasonable, though not certain assumption.

Comment: @chux: Both parts boil to POSIX.1 ISO standard [rationale describing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_12) *"`ssize_t` is intended as the signed analog of `size_t` ... implementation may either choose to use a longer type or simply to use the signed version of the type that underlies size_t."*, but all existing implementations use the latter.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for the very insightful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282953/strlen-not-returning-correct-number-of-characters/54283170?noredirect=1#comment95405265_54283170) and [rational link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_12).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `read` doesn't put the null terminator in `buffer`.  If you run your program with `valgrind`, you'll almost certainly see errors about an invalid read since `buffer` is uninitialized.

You have a few options:

- Don't use `read`, but something that will add the null terminator automatically.
- Use `read`, but add the null terminator manually.  `buffer[readIn] = '\0'` is a naive solution (missing error and bounds checking).
- Initialize `buffer` to nothing but null terminators.  This won't work if your input is larger than `BUF_SIZE`, so be careful.