# What does "signed `size_t`" mean in the printf documentation?

Tags: c

I was looking through the printf documentation on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and I noticed that when using the `z` modifier along with the `d` specifier the type is listed as "signed `size_t`". This made me curious so I looked into why it wasn't using `ssize_t` only to find out that `ssize_t` is a POSIX type rather than a standard type. So, what type is this expecting? I can't find anything other than `ssize_t` when looking for a signed `size_t` type.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm asking what data type would I use to represent a signed `size_t`

Comment: See also [How to use “zd” specifier with `printf()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "signed `size_t`" is used informally, and does not appear in the language standard. In fact it would be a syntax error if you tried to use it in C code.

The C standard says that the `z` length modifier:

> Specifies that a following **`d`**, **`i`**, **`o`**, **`u`**, **`x`**, or **`X`** conversion specifier
>   applies to a **`size_t`** or the corresponding signed integer type argument;
>   or that a following **`n`** conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a
>   signed integer type corresponding to **`size_t`** argument.

There is no portable way to determine what that corresponding signed integer type is. Even the POSIX-specific `ssize_t` type (defined in `<sys/types.h>`) is not specified to be the signed type corresponding to `size_t`. And as chux points out in a comment, it might make sense in some implementations for `ssize_t` to be wider than `size_t`, so it can represent all values up to `SIZE_MAX` (plus, of course, negative values).

In practice, `size_t` will usually be a typedef for one of the predefined unsigned integer types, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, or `unsigned long long int`, and `%zd` would then require an argument of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, respectively. It's also possible that `size_t` is defined in terms of some *extended integer type*.

My guess is that the authors of the standard simply didn't want to go to the effort of specifying that the `z` length modifier applies only to a signed type. Doing so would have added complexity with no real benefit. If you're using a POSIX-conforming implementation, you can *probably* use `%zd` to print a value of type `ssize_t`.

There's no portable use for `%zd`, but having it there in `printf` is harmless, and probably easier than not having it there.

Comment: "I can't think of any good reason for it not to be" --> `ssize_t` could be a wider type than `size_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point. It would have to be if it needs to represent values up to `SIZE_MAX`. (But in many implementations, there is no predefined integer type wider than `size_t`.)

Comment: "There is no portable way to determine what that corresponding signed integer type is." --> Always up for the challenge:  `#define isize_t_name _Generic((size_t)1, \
unsigned: "int", \
unsigned long: "long", \
unsigned long long: "long long", \
default: "TBD" \
) ...  printf("%s\n", isize_t_name);` is close.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, I had thought about using `_Generic`, but it won't work if `size_t` is defined as an extended integer type. Probably no existing implementations do that, so your solution is only portable to all existing implementations, not to all possible conforming implementations. Also, it "determines" the type only in the sense of yielding a string that's the name of the type; that still doesn't let you define an object of the type that would be called `signed size_t` if that syntax were valid. (And it should cover `signed char` and `signed short`, implausible though that is.)

Comment: "it "determines" the type only in the sense of yielding a string that's the name of the type" -> Yes, the challenge looked broad enough for this to be a successful counter example.     "still doesn't let you define an object of the type" - well that is a  requirement [beyond the challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep). I did code up a `_Generic` type caster to the _signed_ `size_t`. Perhaps if `auto` arrives in C22, we can code `auto sign_size = generic_foo(0);`.  Of course this is all in fun as there is scant need for _signed_ `size_t`.

Answer (score 5):

The exact type of a "signed `size_t`" is implementation-defined and AFAIK, there's no standard way to get the type. So I don't see a way to use `%zd` portably. On most platforms, `ptrdiff_t` should be the signed version of `size_t`, but this isn't guaranteed. In fact, there's a `t` format modifier for `ptrdiff_t` which can also be used with a `u` specifier like `%tu`, meaning an "unsigned `ptrdiff_t`". I think these combinations are only for completeness and don't have a practical use.