# Sorting an array in C(small elements at the edges, large ones in the middle)

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

In the array a(n), put the smallest element in the first place, the smallest of the remaining elements in the last place, the next largest in the second place, the next one in the penultimate place, and so on - until the middle of the array.
3 6 1 8 5 --->
1 5 8 6 3
To begin with, I suppose  need to sort the array in ascending order, which I did.And then, if the element number in the sorted array is even, then rewrite them to the beginning of the new array.If it is odd, then go to the end.But I don't know how to do it.Perhaps the problem needs to be solved in a different way.Please help

Comment: This problem is underspecified. How would the output look for `1 2 3 4 5`? How would it look for `2 4 6 8 10`? For `1 1 1 2 2 2`?

Comment: This is unfortunately not stated in the task.Only this condition is given.

Comment: Let me suggest `1 2 3 4 5 -> 1 3 5 4 2`, `2 4 6 8 10 -> 2 6 10 8 4` and `1 1 1 2 2 2 -> 1 1 2 2 2 1`.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I think it is specified well enough. Your approach sound legit, and if there are no complexity constraints - go with it. Regarding how to do it - create two arrays - one of the odd-placed elements, one of the even placed once. Then reverse the second one and append to the first one.

Comment: First sort the input in descending order. Then create a new array of the same size. From the sorted array, take the largest element and copy to the exact middle (size / 2) of the new array. Take the next largest element, and place it to the left of the largest element. Take the next next largest element and copy it to the right of the largest value. Continue like this placing alternate left or right. The descending sorting is to make it easier to get largest to smallest value from the input array. Can be done in a single loop after sorting.

Comment: Another way to think about it, is to think about it as a *spiral*. Draw the array in a piece of paper. Then from the middle element, draw a widening spiral touching every element in the array. This is the order in which you place the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already sorted the array, you can interleave the data with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
        size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
        int b[n];
        int *s = b, *e = b + n;
        for( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                *( i % 2 ? --e : s++ ) = a[i];
        }
        for( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                printf("b[%zu] = %d\n", i, b[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

In other words, start with one pointer at the beginning of the array and one pointer at the end of the array.  Walk the source array inserting the values into the appropriate place in the target.

Comment: I suppose it's a bit obscure, but it is simple.  That is just shorthand for `if( i % 2 ) {e -= 1; *e = a[i];}  else {*s = a[i]; s += 1; }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell  I do not know, but the compiler gives errors :((

Comment: @Yuikus Which compiler?  It compiles cleanly with -Wall -Wextra on gcc (Debian 10.2.0-15) 10.2.0

Comment: Also compiles clean with (clang-1200.0.32.21)

Comment: @WilliamPursell You use `%zd` in the printf, but `i` is of unsigned type `size_t`. It should be `%zu`. See also: [How to use `%zd` specifier with `printf`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926467/3080723)

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted and you are allowed to return a new array rather than modifying the current array in place, it's pretty straightforward.
Just iterate over the array with a simple loop. Keep three indices: one index `i` in the first array, going forward; one index `j` in the new array, going forward; one index `k` in the new array, going backward.

```
source = { 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 }
           ^i
dest   = {                     }
           ^j                ^k

source = { 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 }
                 ^i
dest   = { 1  3              2 }
              ^j          ^k

source = { 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 }
                               ^i
dest   = { 1  3  5  7  6  4  2 }
                    ^k ^j
```

Code:

```c
void permutationAlternate(int *dest, int const *source, size_t size)
{
    size_t i,j,k;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = size - 1;
    while (i < size)
    {
        dest[j] = source[i];
        j++;
        i++;
        dest[k] = source[i];
        k--;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spiraling outward and in is probably better (and simpler) than my inward to out spiral. Also good stepwise explanation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I like it better this way because I hate having to "guess" where the "middle" of the array will end up, and having to check separately odd-size and even-size, etc.

Comment: @Stef Thanks!Sorry, but how do I output a new array, haha? :''')

Comment: @Yuikus: `for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) ; ++i) printf("%d ", array[i]);` should do it. Replace `array` with the name of your array variable and you're good to go.