# Usage of zd vs lu for sizeof

Tags: c, printf, sizeof, size-t, conversion-specifier

I understand that `%zd` is the suggested way to format the `sizeof` result. However, I don't understand why that is necessary. For example using `lu` gives me the same output, and isn't the result of `sizeof` an unsigned long anyways? For example:

```
printf("Sizeof(char): %lu, Sizeof(short): %lu, Sizeof(int): %lu, Sizeof(long): %lu, Sizeof(long long): %lu, Sizeof(float): %lu, Sizeof(double): %lu, Sizeof(long double): %lu\n"
       ,sizeof(char), sizeof(short), sizeof(int), sizeof(long), sizeof(long long), sizeof(float), sizeof(double), sizeof(long double));
printf("Sizeof(char): %zd, Sizeof(short): %zd, Sizeof(int): %zd, Sizeof(long): %zd, Sizeof(long long): %zd, Sizeof(float): %zd, Sizeof(double): %zd, Sizeof(long double): %zd"
       ,sizeof(char), sizeof(short), sizeof(int), sizeof(long), sizeof(long long), sizeof(float), sizeof(double), sizeof(long double));
```

> Sizeof(char): 1, Sizeof(short): 2, Sizeof(int): 4, Sizeof(long): 8, Sizeof(long long): 8, Sizeof(float): 4, Sizeof(double): 8, Sizeof(long double): 16 
> Sizeof(char): 1, Sizeof(short): 2, Sizeof(int): 4, Sizeof(long): 8, Sizeof(long long): 8, Sizeof(float): 4, Sizeof(double): 8, Sizeof(long double): 16

What's the reason or advantage of using `%zd` and why was that added in the first place?

Comment: The result of `sizeof` is a `size_t`, which may or may not be the same as an `unsigned long`, depending on the compiler, OS, and processor that you're using. And the format specifier is `%zu`, since `size_t` is unsigned.

Comment: I wanna say [because Microsoft](https://godbolt.org/z/KTT4P9)... (but in reality they're probably not the only ones).

Comment: @user3386109 I see, so is `size_t` something like `typedef size_t int` or `typedef size_t <something-else>` depending on the platform?

Comment: @carl.hiass Yes, that's the general idea, although it may be a builtin type, not a typedef.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926467/11455105) answer out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "zd" specifier with \`printf()\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916575/how-to-use-zd-specifier-with-printf)

Comment: @Siguza `long` is almost never `size_t` on most embedded systems

Comment: If `size_t` and `unsigned long` and `unsigned int` are all 32-bit size (and they can be), it does not matter whether you use `%zu` or `%lu` or `%u`, but the code is not portable. That's why you need to use the right specifier – so that `printf()` knows the size of the argument that is passed. All it has is a *promise* from the format specifier and must believe the caller passed the correct size operand. It has no other way of knowing, and is up to the programmer to match the format with the type.

Answer (score 4):

The value returned by the operator `sizeof` has the type `size_t`.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 5 The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined,
> and its type (an unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in
> <stddef.h> (and other headers).

The type `size_t` is an implementation defined unsigned integer type. Usually it is defined as an alias for the type unsigned long though the C Standard does not require this. In particularly the Standard allows that the rank of the type `size_t` can be greater than the rank of the type unsigned long.

From the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>)

> 4 The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.

So to output values of the type size_t you should use the conversion specifier `zu`.

Answer (score 2):

> isn't the result of `sizeof` an unsigned long anyways?

No, it returns a `size_t`, and a `size_t` needs not be the same size as an `unsigned long`.

For example, in the Windows world, an `unsigned long` is 32 bits and a `size_t` is 64 bits.

> I understand that `%zd` is the suggested way to format the `sizeof` result.

Not quite.

Use `%zu` for `size_t` (or `%zX`, `%zx` or `%zo`)
Use `%zd` for `ssize_t`<sup>[1]</sup>

Since `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, you want `%zu`.

---

1. `%zd` is a *de facto* standard, not a *de jure* standard. There is none of the latter for printing `ssize_t`, which is a type defined by POSIX (not C).

Comment: Is there a `ssize_t` in standard C? cppreference says `%zd` is for "signed size_t", and I am not sure what that means.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926467/10147399) answer sheds some light on the matter and it also mentions that `ssize_t` is a POSIX thing and isn't necessarily the signed version of `size_t`. So saying `%zd` is for `ssize_t` is not accurate.

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili, Re "*Is there a `ssize_t` in standard C?*", I did not say there was. /// Re "*it also mentions that `ssize_t` isn't necessarily the signed version of `size_t`*", Actually, it pretty much says the opposite. It points out the while the POSIX spec doesn't explicitly say the type is a match, it is understood to be.

Comment: Sure, in practice `ssize_t` is the signed `size_t`, but so is `ptrdiff_t` and `%zd` is likely to work fine on any signed integer that has the same size as `size_t`. I wanted to mention what guarantees exist in what standards in case OP is interested.

Comment: @ikegami The POSIX rationale says "his is intended to be a signed analog of size_t. The wording is such that an implementation may either choose to use a longer type or simply to use the signed version of the type that underlies size_t."  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_05