# How do I construct a "signed size_t" for use with scanf("%zn")?

Tags: c, scanf, size-t

I tried to obtain the number of characters read as a `size_t`, using this program:¹

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    sscanf("abc", "%*s%zn", &i);
    printf("%zu", i);
}
```

GCC 12 warns about this:

```
scanf.c: In function ‘main’:
scanf.c:7:25: warning: format ‘%zn’ expects argument of type ‘signed size_t *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t *’ {aka ‘long unsigned int *’} [-Wformat=]
    7 |     sscanf("abc", "%*s%zn", &i);
      |                       ~~^   ~~
      |                         |   |
      |                         |   size_t * {aka long unsigned int *}
      |                         long int *
      |                       %ln
```

And it's correct² do do so; in the [C17 draft standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http%3a//www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#subsection.7.21.6), page 234, we read (my emphasis)

> No input is consumed. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to **signed** integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the `fscanf` function.

Earlier standards contain similar wording.

So how do I (portably) create a signed equivalent of `size_t` for this conversion?

In C++, I could use `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`, but that's obviously not an option for C code.  Without that, it seems that `%zn` conversion is unusable in C.

---

¹ The real-world case from which this arises came from [reviewing *Simple photomosaic generator*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/282674/75307), where we wanted a more general form of `strto()`, and so need `%n` to determine the end of conversion.  I know we can use plain `int` for all  here, but wanted to check the expected behaviour before reporting as a bug.

² Other than calling the required type `signed size_t *`, which is obviously not a valid C type name.

Comment: Do you get the warning with `ssize_t`?

Comment: Some environments define `ssize_t` as a signed version of `size_t`.  I don't know if the standard requires it, so it might not be portable, but if it's available to you then it should work.

Comment: @TomKarzes neither C18 or C23 mention `ssize_t`.

Comment: `signed size_t` is not a valid type, the message is bogus.

Comment: @TomKarzes `size_t` is not defined under POSIX as "signed `size_t`".  [It's defined by POSIX as](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html): "The type `ssize_t` shall be capable of storing values at least in the range `[-1, {SSIZE_MAX}]`."  The only negative number it's guaranteed to hold is `-1`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Huh, that seems like a strange definition.

Comment: There's also `ptrdiff_t` which some libraries define in `stddef.h`.  I suspect in practice all three of these types usually have the same size, with `size_t` being unsigned and the others being signed, but apparently the other two types aren't standard, and when available, they aren't all required to have the same size.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, C17 doesn't define that type, so the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I construct a "signed size_t" for use with `scanf("%zn")`?

You are out of luck.  As of C17

> `z` Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, X, or n conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `size_t` or the *corresponding signed integer type*. C17dr § 7.21.6.2 11

> `n` No input is consumed. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to **signed** integer .... C17dr § 7.21.6.2 12

And `size_t` is an *unsigned* type.

Yet C never details how to make the *corresponding signed integer type*.

There is no *specified* signed type corresponding to `size_t` in standard C.

---

Alternatives:

- Live with `"%n", &int_object` and then `size_t i = (unsigned) int_object;`.  (Cast important)
- Use `"%jn", &intmax_t_object` and then `size_t i = (size_t) intmax_t_object;`.

---

If pressed to typedef a `signed_size_t`, the following *should* portably work, but you are on your own.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if SIZE_MAX == UINT_MAX
  typedef int signed_size_t;
#elif SIZE_MAX == ULONG_MAX
  typedef long signed_size_t;
#elif SIZE_MAX == ULLONG_MAX
  typedef long long signed_size_t;
#elif SIZE_MAX == UINTMAX_MAX;
  typedef intmax_t signed_size_t;
#elif SIZE_MAX == USHRT_MAX
  typedef short signed_size_t;
#else
  #error Strange `size_t`.
#endif

_Static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(signed_size_t), "Strange size_t");
```

---

**About non-standard `ssize_t`**

`ssize_t` is not a certain match for the *corresponding signed integer type*.

Even [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html) has:

> `ssize_t`
> This is intended to be a signed analog of `size_t`. The wording is such that an implementation may either choose to use a **longer type** or simply to use the signed version of the type that underlies `size_t`. ...

---

Similar question [How to use "zd" specifier with `printf()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359).

Comment: Thanks.  It does indeed seem that `%zn` is useless (perhaps it's worth proposing `%N` as an unsigned version of `%n`?).  I like the suggestion of using a `%jn` conversion, since `uintmax_t` must be have at least the range of `size_t`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Almost certainly `ptrdiff_t` is the signed version of `size_t` (even if it's pedantically not). So, maybe use that?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Your comment "certainly ptrdiff_t is the signed version of size_t" deserves to be an answer, even if I disagree with it.  Perhaps others will.

Answer (score 2):

"signed `size_t`" doesn't really exist as a standard-defined type, in either POSIX or any version of the C standard.

[POSIX `ssize_t`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) is specified as "The type `ssize_t` shall be capable of storing values at least in the range `[-1, {SSIZE_MAX}]`.", so even if `ssize_t` is available, it's not strictly suitable for use as a "signed `size_t`" value.

While there's no type that's guaranteed to be large enough to hold a "signed `size_t`" type of value in strictly-conforming code, on all platforms that I'm aware of, the standard type `long long int` seems to me to be the most "future proof".  (The odds of `size_t` being larger than `unsigned long long int` are IMO likely somewhere between zero and infinitesimal, but I don't think that's precluded by any version of the C standard.)

As I write this, no platform that I'm aware of uses a `size_t` value larger than 64 bits, and `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, so it will be large enough.

`int64_t` seems like it would be a good choice, but should a system ever have a `size_t` larger than 64 bits, `int64_t` would fail.  I suspect that any system implementation with `size_t` larger than 64 bits would likely expand `long long int` to match.

You could always add something like this to your code to protect yourself

```
#if SIZE_MAX > ULLONG_MAX
#error size_t larger than unsigned long long int
#endif
```

Nevermind it's easier to use the `" %lld ..."` format specifier to scan a `long long int` than it is to use the `" " SCNd64 " ..."` macro to scan an `int64_t`...

If you really want to create a "matching signed `size_t`" type, you could expand on using `SIZE_MAX` in a `#if` ladder, comparing it to various `U*MAX` values to find the "most correct" matching signed integer type to use in a `typedef`.  But then you'd have to create your own `scanf()` (and maybe `printf()` macros).

**OR...**

Or you could just pedantically play with fire and use `ssize_t` on POSIX systems, and create your own `ssize_t` on non-POSIX systems.  IME there are no `ssize_t` implementations that don't *de facto* act as a "signed `size_t`" value.

Comment: We need a _pointer_ to the correct type, so just using `long long int` or any other defined type is non-portable here.  As chux's answer says, probably the best option is to use `%jn` conversion, and then cast the written-to value.

Comment: "easier to use the " %lld ..." format specifier to scan a long long int than it is to use the " " SCNd64 " ..." macro to scan an int64_t.." -->  true.  It should be `"%" SCNd64 "..."`.  (missing %)

Comment: Probably should be using `int_fast64_t` rather than an optional type such as `int64_t`.

Comment: @TobySpeight `int_fast64_t` is not more guaranteed to hold whatever the "signed `size_t`" value than `int64_t`.  Unless C34 or similar creates a `long long long int`, `long long int` is almost certainly going to be the largest integer value provided by any future implementation, and it could be 128 bits while `int_fast64_t` could very well remain at 64 bits.  If such an architecture used a 128-bit `size_t` `int_fast64_t` might not work as it could easily be a mere 64-bit `[long] int`, but `long long int` would probably be 128 bits.

Comment: `int_fast64_t` _is_ mandated, while `int64_t` isn't.  That's why it's a better choice.  In any case `intmax_t` is better than both.